# Some clients cannot access their websites or mail, but I can. Not sure whats wrong

Tags: web-hosting, google-search-console, vps

I have about 5 clients whose sites are hosted on our VPS who cannot access their sites from their office computers. DNS is fine and there doesnt seem to be anything wrong with the host - no downtime and bandwidth limits and size is ok.

Webmaster Tools also indicates nothing is wrong. I can access the site from several locations (office, home, friends place) but the clients cannot.

I am at a loss as to what could be causing this. Could this be an issue with their ISP?

Comment: This may be because of DNS resolve issue, check the hosting configurations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a good place to check. I have had several clients in the past that have had similar problems which was directly related to their internet service provider. More so for emails as some ISPs require you to use their own mail servers e.g. Telstra Business

Also, this might sound silly, but make sure they are searching for the website in the url bar and not Google search which does not instantly index new websites, this is also a common problem for non computer savvy clients.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that their ISP blocked or even redlisted your IP address. You may want to add their office IP addresses to your VPS safe list.